# How to make iphone setting type menu into twitter bootstrap for mobile view

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I want to make iphone settings style menu into twitter bootstrap. I have vertical menu on left side, which works correctly. Now I want to apply iphone settings style menu (something like this http://filamentgroup.com/examples/menus/ipod.php) when site open through mobile devices.
As I don't want to use the default menu style given by bootstrap(for mobile), so want to try something new.

I have just used html,jquery and css, no scripting language.